# Calculator app for Android

Tags: android

I'm thinking about an algorithm for building a calculator. My first idea was to do an array and after click some button save the value of pressed button to this array. And after click the button "=" I would walked this array via cycle for (for example) and from entered value I will make up the expression - for example:
 1.iteration - "5"
 2.iteration - "5"
 3.iteration - "+"
 4.iteration - "8"
 END OF ARRAY

So the result expression will be: 55+8

But I'm not sure, if this idea is right - I think it's a bit complication -- exist some pretty way, how to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would tokenize the string and build an abstract syntax tree which you could then walk to evaluate the children

Answer (score 0):

dont use an array.. just use variables its enough. have one text box just type in the text box say(55). after you pressed any operators(+,-,*,/) just store that(55) in A variable. after that you enter 8. add that 8 to the 55.. use two variables.. any doubt means pls communicate with me